# Expected unqualified-id before 'public'

Tags: esp8266, programming, array

I'm making an arduino program for a buzzer that you can record notes and song for and then play them back. I have 2 arrays that hold both pitch and if a note is being played. I continue to get errors that say `expected unqualified-id before 'public'`.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

```
void setup() 
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(5, INPUT_PULLUP);
 pinMode(14, INPUT_PULLUP);
 pinMode(12, INPUT_PULLUP);
}




void freePlayMode()
{
    int readP = analogRead(0);
  int readB = digitalRead(5);
  readP = map(readP, 0, 1023, 300, 2000);
  Serial.println(readP);
  if (readB == LOW)
  {
  tone(4, readP);
  }
  else
  {
    noTone(4);
  }
}





void recordMode()
{
 int readS2 = digitalRead(12);
 if (readS2 == LOW)
 {
  rec();
 }
 else
 {
  if (readS2 == HIGH)
  {
    playBack();
  }
 }
}










void rec()
{

static public int recordings[99999999] = {NULL};
static public int notes[99999999] = {NULL};
int state;
static unsigned long i = 0;
int readP = analogRead(0);
  int readB = digitalRead(5);
  readP = map(readP, 0, 1023, 300, 2000);
  Serial.println(readP);
  if (readB == LOW)
  {
  tone(4, readP);
  }
  else
  {
    noTone(4);
  }

  if (i < 99999999)
 {
  if (readB == HIGH)
  {
    state == 0;
  }
  else
  {
    state == 1;
  }
  recordings[i] = state;
  notes[i] = readP;
  i++;


 }
}




void playBack()
{

}






void loop() 
{
int readS1 = digitalRead(14);
if (readS1 == LOW)
{
  freePlayMode();
}
else
{
  if (readS1 == HIGH)
  {
    recordMode();
  }
}





}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static public int recordings[99999999] = {NULL}
```

This is not valid C code. Remove the word `public`.
Also you cannot create such a big array. The Arduino has only 2 KB (SRAM) memory and also since it is static you have to fill it with values directly, like:

```
static int recordings[5] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

How many values you want to store?

In case you need quite a lot (like hundreds), I would use a different solution for the `state` array as it only stores values 0 or 1. For example, you can use arrays of uint8_t which cost only 1 byte per element, but even better would be to store 8 0 or 1 (boolean) values in one byte each, but that means you have to get/set the values in the correct indices yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, the arrays used up way to much memory. I appreciate the help.

Comment: You're welcome.